# How do I transfer Pokemon from Black 2 to X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

Like the title states, I'd like to transfer my Pokemon into the new game. I'd like to get my Pokemon to be Mega Evolved in Pokemon X

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait until December 27th, when the [Pokemon Bank](http://www.serebii.net/bank/) and the PokeTransporter app come out.

Also note: [Only certain Pokemon can Mega Evolve](http://serebii.net/xy/megaevolutions.shtml).

Comment: Thank you, @Robotnik. I couldn't get it to do that when I tried. =/

Comment: that's cool, it's pretty easy. Just hit the little chain-link symbol, paste your link, and change the 'enter link description' text and you're done! :)

Comment: That's actually what I did, and it put the link next to the description. xDD I'll be better about that now, though.